# Notice: Table doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a script to display my MYSQL db info and I keep getting these errors:

> Notice: Table 'head1sta_news.news' doesn't exist in
>   /home/head1sta/public_html/index.php on line 103

And:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in /home/head1sta/public_html/index.php on line 104

It has varied as I have tweaked the code here and there trying to figure out what I am messing up on. This is the script:

```
<?
mysql_connect("localhost", "****_news", "****");
mysql_select_db("****_news");
$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
  echo("$data[1] , $data[0] , $data[3]");
}
?>
```

Comment: Error message is so clear. **Table 'head1sta_news.news' doesn't exist**

Comment: verify your `mysql_connect` is working my guess is there is a problem in the connection.

Comment: ***SQL Injection***... D:

Comment: @deceze: Actually, that error doesn't appear on the reference page. I guess "Table doesn't exist" was assumed to intuitively mean that the "table doesn't exist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent set up for database correctly it doesnt have the table / the user doesnt have permission to see the table

```
head1sta_news.news
```

By the table name above i assume your reading from a head first book ? If so PLEASE get a more recent version, If its suggesting mysql_connect its at least a few years out of date.

The second error is actually a result of the first not being handled correctly also.